# Getting distinct values from aggregate result in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My data has the following format:

```
[
  {
    "level_1": "A",
    "cols": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "arno": "DC",
    "table": [
      {
        country: "NO",
        population: 400,
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        country: "AE",
        population: 100,
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        country: "OT",
        population: 200,
        color: "blue"
      },
      {
        country: "AU",
        population: 200,
        color: "red",
        alo: "n"
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "level_1": "A",
    "cols": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "arno": "CD",
    "table": [
      {
        country: "NO",
        population: 200,
        color: "blue",
        "Supplier Manager": "['Arnold Khan']"
      },
      {
        country: "AE",
        population: 200,
        color: "red",
        "Supplier Manager": "[]"
      },
      {
        country: "AE",
        population: 200,
        color: "green",
        "Supplier Manager": "['Arnold Khan']"
      },
      {
        country: "OT",
        population: 200,
        color: "blue",
        "Supplier Manager": "['Adam Nor', 'Jim Brown']"
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "level_1": "B",
    "cols": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "arno": "CD",
    "table": [
      {
        country: "AL",
        population: 400,
        color: "red",
        alo: "y"
      },
      {
        country: "AR",
        population: 100,
        color: "green",
        alo: "y"
      },
      {
        country: "YU",
        population: 200,
        color: "red",
        alo: "y"
      },
      {
        country: "AX",
        population: 200,
        color: "red",
        alo: "n"
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

I am running the following query to retrieve the values from nested array `table` inside of all objects in my database:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$and": [
        {
          "level_1": "A"
        },
        {
          "arno": "CD"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "table": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$table",
          "as": "t",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$or": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$t.color",
                      "blue"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$t.color",
                      "red"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$t.population",
                  200
                ]
              },
              {
                "$or": [
                  {
                    "$regexMatch": {
                      "input": "$$t.Supplier Manager",
                      "regex": "Jim Brown",
                      "options": "i"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "$regexMatch": {
                      "input": "$$t.Supplier Manager",
                      "regex": "Arnold Khan",
                      "options": "i"
                    }
                  },
                  
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Now the result I get is this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "arno": "CD",
    "cols": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "level_1": "A",
    "table": [
      {
        "Supplier Manager": "['Arnold Khan']",
        "color": "blue",
        "country": "NO",
        "population": 200
      },
      {
        "Supplier Manager": "['Adam Nor', 'Jim Brown']",
        "color": "blue",
        "country": "OT",
        "population": 200
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which is correct, but I want now to get list distinct values for each variable in the `table` array of objects from aggregating into this result for the `table` array output.
Like for example get distinct:

```
'color' : ["blue"]
'country' : ["OT", "NO"]
'population' : [200]
...
```

Is this achievable in Mongodb aggregate query or is it better to load this into Pandas DataFrame and retrieve it from there?

Working playground example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VSOZ2YVQa4w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$setUnion`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to distinct the value in the array.

```
{
  $set: {
    color: {
      $setUnion: "$table.color"
    },
    country: {
      $setUnion: "$table.country"
    },
    population: {
      $setUnion: "$table.population"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rTJ574lJm8b)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @[Yong Shun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8017690/yong-shun) is correct, but you can make some cosmetic improvements.

```
{
  $match: {
    "$and": [
      {
        "level_1": "A"
      },
      {
        "arno": "CD"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can be written as

```
{ $match: { level_1: "A", arno: "CD" } }
```

and this

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "$eq": [
        "$$t.color",
        "blue"
      ]
    },
    {
      "$eq": [
        "$$t.color",
        "red"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can be written as

```
{$in: ["$$t.color", ["red","blue"]]}
```

and this

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "$regexMatch": {
        "input": "$$t.Supplier Manager",
        "regex": "Jim Brown",
        "options": "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "$regexMatch": {
        "input": "$$t.Supplier Manager",
        "regex": "Arnold Khan",
        "options": "i"
      }
    }        
  ]
}
```

Can be written as

```
{
  "$regexMatch": {
    "input": "$$t.Supplier Manager",
    "regex": "(Jim Brown)|(Arnold Khan)",
    "options": "i"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sg9FL0wDyhQ